# Convert duration to total milliseconds

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I have a string field in my Elastic Search that has a duration in the format `00:00:00.000000`. I want to convert that to a number field that is the total number of milliseconds.

Edit:

I thought of using a Scripted field but it isn't working.

```
try{
    String duration = doc['app.duration'].value;

    String[] durationParts = new String[3];
    
    int firstIdx = duration.indexOf(":");
    int secondIdx = duration.indexOf(":", firstIdx+1);
        
    durationParts[1] = duration.substring(firstIdx+1, secondIdx);
    durationParts[2] = duration.substring(secondIdx+1);
        
    long minutes = Long.parseLong(durationParts[1]) * 60000;
    float seconds = Float.parseFloat(durationParts[2]) * 1000;
    
    long mAndS = Math.round(minutes + seconds);
    return mAndS;
}
catch(Exception e) {
    return -1;
}
```

The above fails on the first line `String duration = doc['app.duration'].value;` and I get -1. However if I change that first line to a hard coded value like `String duration = "00:00:01.5250000";` then I get out the expected `1525` that I expect.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. From what I read using the `doc` object is how fields are accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the `keyword` sub-field instead as it contains the exact raw string value that you added into the source (i.e. `00:00:00.000000`), while the `app.duration` field contains the analyzed text value which might not be what you expect depending on the analyzers you have set up.

```
 doc['app.duration.keyword'].value
```

Otherwise, a simpler script to get what you want, i.e. 0 and 1525, is the following:

```
    def parts = /:/.split(doc['app.duration'].value);
    def total = 0;
    total += Long.parseLong(parts[0]) * 24 * 60 * 1000;
    total += Long.parseLong(parts[1]) * 60 * 1000;
    total += Float.parseFloat(parts[2]) * 1000;
    return total;
```

Note that you need to add the following line to your `elasticsearch.yml` config file in order to enable the regular expression engine.

```
script.painless.regex.enabled: true
```

Comment: Where is your ES server running?

Comment: I'm not really sure. It's hosted by my company. I don't really have access to that. The above code I showed does work without using the split if I test with a hard coded value instead of pulling from `doc`. My real issue is `doc['app.duration']` doesn't return anything and causes an error. I don't think split would resolve that. What does `keyword` do?

Comment: Can you show the mapping of the `app.duration` field please? It might be that certain documents don't have any value for that field. Is that possible?

Comment: Also can you add this in the catch block `Debug.explain(e)` and update your question with the results?

Comment: Adding `Debug.explain(e)` resulted in returning an empty array `[]`. It looks like the difference was between `doc['app.duration'].value` which doesn't work and `doc['app.duration.keyword'].value` which does work.I don't really know what that `keyword` part means but it seems to have been the issue.

Comment: Great, I've updated my answer accordingly. Please check